# Database not updated after query

Tags: php, mysql

mistake was as follow. if you notice the name of the input field in the form is zipcode and in the dynamic script in this case php I was calling it as 'zip' instead of 'zipcode'
Thank you guys

```
  if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "editform"){
       $zip = $_POST['zip'];  
   }

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data>
 <td><input name="zipcode" type="text" class="formFields" id="zipcode" value="<?php print "$zip"; ?>" size="32" maxlength="24" /></td> <td><p><br />
            <input name="parse_var" type="hidden" value="editform" />
              <input type="submit" name="Submit3" value="Submit Form" />
            </p></td>

</form>
```

Comment: put 3-5 lines max of relevant code ONLY

Comment: +1 for mysql_real_escape_string, -500 for using eregi. The ereg system is deprecated, and you should switch to using preg_*() instead.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your query. It may be an issue with your schema or you can't connect. Try printing or echoing $errorde. It's a string, there shouldn't be a reason to use var_dump on it.

Comment: If all else fails you can print the query and execute it through phpMyAdmin or any other DBMS you use manually and see what error it produces.

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars` when putting data in a database, use that function when actually *outputting* HTML.

Comment: Still is not updating don't know hwy.

Comment: I see that I have website and  youtube fields NULL in the database plus I didn't have a bio_body field in the table let me see how it results once I add the table field

Comment: I was missing three POST variable let me see if they will fix the issue$firstname= $_POST['fullname'];
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

Comment: I fixed it it was a simple error. In the form I call one of the input field name was called zip, and when parsing it in php I was calling zipcode instead of zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `$id` being set? None of your code seems to actually set it, so most likely your query is coming out to

```
UPDATE .... WHERE category_id=''
```

That's a valid query, but probably doesn't match anything in your database. That's NOT an error condition, it's just a query that happens to match nothing.

Comment: Thanks marc, for the observation and you time but I do have set, I didn't post it in the code but it is up in there.

Comment: Then I'd suggest removing the 'fluff' from your code sample and putting in something that truly represents the problem. Because as it stands right now, there's nothing really wrong that we can see.

Comment: there was three fields I was not POST ing and found in the form   $firstname= $_POST['fullname'];
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

Comment: I fixed it it was a simple error. In the form I call one of the input field name was called zip, and when parsing it in php I was calling zipcode instead of zip